# Best way of creating a record cache ( Memcache in this example )

Tags: php, caching, memcached

I want to use a caching mechanism to help with performance in a PHP application and came across memcache as what seems like a good option.  Then looking into it I found a more general problem with caching...

The problems I see though is that if as in the examples I simply use the SQL statement as a hashed key to the cached results, then there is a possible case of duplicate records.  This would occur if SQL A would fetch records 1, 2, 4 and SQL B would fetch records 2, 3 and 6.  In this case record 2 would be in both result sets.  If I simply retrieve the record and then link to the same record - I'm not really getting any performance increase and would probably slow the application down.

Someone else must have come across this - so I wonder what anyone would suggest as to a better way of managing the cache.  Or is it to simple not go for caching and always rely on the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why even worry about this? The point is that the query is cached. If the results of two different queries partially overlap, well, so be it. Unless those results are many many megabytes in size and hence take a lot of space, it doesn't matter. What does matter is that if you want to run the same query again, you don't need to, because the results are already cached.

Comment: That makes sense - although it prompts a new problem.  If I alter record 2 from SQL A, should I 'invalidate' the cache for SQL B?  If not then the values in SQL B are out of date.  Or does this escalate to if I update any record - do I throw away all of my cached results?

Comment: That's where it comes down to the details of your caching strategy and which is more efficient. For infrequent updates, it can make sense to simply clean the whole cache upon any update. For frequent updates on a popular site, it may make sense to clean the whole cache every x minutes, so the whole site will seem to be static for x minutes. Etc, etc. There are many possible strategies.

Comment: I've been thinking of deleting this question for some time (as it's badly asked and probably not worth updating).  As you are the only person this affects, I just wanted to ask if that's OK and how I can do it.

Comment: IMO you could also just leave it as is. Not sure you _can_ delete it, with a positive answer. Do you want me to delete it?